# Retrieving maximum value from sql-vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle

I am trying to retrieve a maximum value from sql - vb.net

This is my code: I get this error:

> *Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type
>   'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader'*

Please help. :(

```
Dim cmd2 As New OracleCommand
cmd2.Connection = conn
'SELECT MAX(LASTNO) FROM d001005 where lbrcode = '104' and CODE1 = 'CASH' and lnodate = '14-NOV-08' 
Dim datepara As String = Date.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yy")
'datepara = "14-NOV-08"
cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(LASTNO) FROM d001005 where lbrcode = '" + lbr + "' and CODE1 = 'CASH' and lnodate = '" + datepara + "'"
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text
Dim dr2 As OracleDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteScalar
Dim result As Decimal = dr2.Item("LASTNO")
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of [SQL injection attacks?!?](http://xkcd.com/327/) - you should **never** concatenate together a SQL statement - [use **parametrized queries** instead](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx) - **always!**

Comment: yes, i am just a beginner. I will surely follow it :) thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **no item with the name "LASTNO"** as you are using an *aggregate function* to find out the maximum value. Furthermore [**ExecuteScalar**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.executescalar.aspx) returns the *first value of the first row*! Another point is, that you should use **[OracleParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleparameter.aspx)** for any kind of dynamic statement, **to prevent SQL injection**!

```
Dim cmd2 As New OracleCommand
cmd2.Connection = conn
Dim datepara As String = Date.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yy") ' see hint below

cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(LASTNO) as maxLastNo FROM d001005 where lbrcode = :lbr and CODE1 = 'CASH' and lnodate = :lnodate"

' add parameter value directly
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("lbr", lbr)   ' lbr seems to be your var which holds the according value

' or create parameter object and set type and add it afterwards
Dim param as new OracleParameter
param.ParameterName = "lnodate"
param.Value = datepara    ' or any other value (furthermore: no need to convert to string)
param.ParameterType = OracleType.DateTime ' or OracleType.Varchar which is set by default
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text

Dim val = cmd2.ExecuteScalar()
if Not val is Nothing then
    Dim maxValue as Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(val)
    Console.WriteLine(maxValue)
End if
```

Comment: thanks! :) that helps. I can't vote up since i am not elligble somehow.

Comment: I have already voted up all the 11 questions. Is it different from "selecting some answers as best solutions?"

Answer (score 3):

Method `ExecuteScalar()` returns `System.Object` so change your code.

```
 Dim value=cmd2.ExecuteScalar()
 IF Not IsNoThing(value) Then
    result=Decimal.Parse(value.ToString())
 End IF
```

Or you can use ExecuteReader,

```
   Dim dr2 As OracleDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
    Dim value as Decimal
    If dr2.Read() Then
       IF Not dr2.IsDbNull(0)
           Value=dr2.GetDecimal(0)
       End IF
    End If
```

And *always* use parameters instead of hardcoded sql string.

```
cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(LASTNO) FROM d001005 where lbrcode=@lbrcode and CODE1='CASH' and lnodate=@lnodate"
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@lbrcode",SqlDbType.VarChar,20).Value=lbr
.....
```

Comment: how do i vote up your answer man? i am trying to but it gives me a damn error saying that i cant >.<