# Conversion from string to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying following piece of code and I am getting following error:

`ex = {"Conversion from string "INSERT INTO d009040 (LBRCODE,ENT" to type 'Double' is not valid."}`.

Please help. So far I could work with longer SQL queries. :(

```
Dim cmd3 As New OracleCommand
                cmd3.Connection = conn
                Dim timepara As String = Now.Hour & Now.Minute & Now.Second & Now.Millisecond
                cmd3.CommandText = "INSERT INTO d009040 (LBRCODE,ENTRYDATE,BATCHCD,SETNO,SCROLLNO,MAINSCROLLNO,POSTDATE,FEFFDATE,ACTIVITYTYPE,CASHFLOWTYPE,VALUEDATE,BOOKTYPE,DRCR,VCRACCTID,MAINACCTID,MAINMODTYPE,VCRMODTYPE,TRNCURCD,FCYTRNAMT,LCYCONVRATE,LCYTRNAMT,INSTRBANKCD,INSTRBRANCHCD,INSTRTYPE,INSTRNO,INSTRDATE,TOKENNO,PARTICULARS,SYSGENVCR,SHTOTFLAG,SHCLRFLAG,ACTOTFLAG,ACCLRFLAG,MAKER,MAKERDATE,MAKERTIME,CHECKER1,CHECKER2,CHECKER3,CHECKER4,CHECKERDATE,CHECKERTIME,NOAUTHPENDING,NOAUTHOVER,POSTFLAG,AUTHFLAG,FEFFFLAG,CANCELEDFLAG,POSTAUTHFEFFCNCL,UPDTCHKID,PARTCLEARAMT,POSTTIME) VALUES ('" + lbr + "','" + datepara + "','TR-MOBDS','" + k + "','" + k + "','" + k + "','" + datepara + "','" + datepara + "','CR','CR','" + datepara + "','ZZ','C','" + internalaccount + "','" + internalaccount + "','47','47','INR','" + amount + "','1','" + amount + "','0','0','99','000000000000','" + datepara + "','0','DDS CR. From Agent','1','Y','Y','Y','Y','0','" + datepara + "','" + timepara + "','0','0','0','0','" + datepara + "','" + timepara + "','0','1','P','A','F','0','0','0','0','" + timepara + "')"
                cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: You are concatenating SQL string. Use Parameterized SQL statement to avoid **such** errors and SQL injection.

Comment: ya but i need to pull this over for time being :)

Comment: @user1051505 It would be *so easy* to use parameterized queries from what you have so far. *Don't just "pull this over"*... you will never get around to fixing it.

Comment: @user1051505 - Take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171604/retrieving-maximum-value-from-sql-vb-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use [`Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleparameter.aspx) to avoid SQL-Injection and such errors.

For example:

```
Using con = New OracleConnection(connectionString)
    Dim sql = "INSERT INTO d009040 (LBRCODE,ENTRYDATE,BATCHCD,SETNO,SCROLLNO,MAINSCROLLNO,POSTDATE,FEFFDATE,ACTIVITYTYPE,CASHFLOWTYPE,VALUEDATE,BOOKTYPE,DRCR,VCRACCTID,MAINACCTID,MAINMODTYPE,VCRMODTYPE,TRNCURCD,FCYTRNAMT,LCYCONVRATE,LCYTRNAMT,INSTRBANKCD,INSTRBRANCHCD,INSTRTYPE,INSTRNO,INSTRDATE,TOKENNO,PARTICULARS,SYSGENVCR,SHTOTFLAG,SHCLRFLAG,ACTOTFLAG,ACCLRFLAG,MAKER,MAKERDATE,MAKERTIME,CHECKER1,CHECKER2,CHECKER3,CHECKER4,CHECKERDATE,CHECKERTIME,NOAUTHPENDING,NOAUTHOVER,POSTFLAG,AUTHFLAG,FEFFFLAG,CANCELEDFLAG,POSTAUTHFEFFCNCL,UPDTCHKID,PARTCLEARAMT,POSTTIME) VALUES (:LBRCODE,:ENTRYDATE,:BATCHCD,:SETNO,:SCROLLNO,:MAINSCROLLNO,:POSTDATE,:FEFFDATE,:ACTIVITYTYPE,:CASHFLOWTYPE,:VALUEDATE,:BOOKTYPE,DRCR,:VCRACCTID,:MAINACCTID,:MAINMODTYPE,:VCRMODTYPE,:TRNCURCD,:FCYTRNAMT,:LCYCONVRATE,:LCYTRNAMT,:INSTRBANKCD,:INSTRBRANCHCD,:INSTRTYPE,:INSTRNO,:INSTRDATE,:TOKENNO,:PARTICULARS,:SYSGENVCR,:SHTOTFLAG,:SHCLRFLAG,:ACTOTFLAG,:ACCLRFLAG,:MAKER,:MAKERDATE,:MAKERTIME,:CHECKER1,:CHECKER2,:CHECKER3,:CHECKER4,:CHECKERDATE,:CHECKERTIME,:NOAUTHPENDING,:NOAUTHOVER,:POSTFLAG,:AUTHFLAG,:FEFFFLAG,:CANCELEDFLAG,:POSTAUTHFEFFCNCL,:UPDTCHKID,:PARTCLEARAMT,:POSTTIME)"
    Using cmd = New OracleCommand(sql, con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":LBRCODE", LBRCODE)
        ' add the other parameters as well ... '
        dim result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

Note that i haven't used oracle for ages so there might be something wrong, but i hope you understand it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It means that one of the values you are providing into your SQL is not convertible to a double type that the corresponding field requires.

Without knowing a) your inputs, and b) your data structure, we can't tell you which one.

You should also research using parameterised queries.

Answer (score 1):

All the values you are passing are enclosed within single quotes - so sql server considers them to be strings. eg: 'string','23' = both are strings.

If the table is expecting a string and 23 as a double your VALUES would be
VALUES('string',23)

So you need to match your many many column type requirements correctly.

As other posters have said - it's probably easier and certainly more maintainable to rewrite it using parameterised queries.

edit: oh - you are using oracle. My bad. The issue with the values-as-strings might be the same so I will leave this post up.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using `VBNET`, you can use the class `CONVERT`

ex.

```
Dim x AS Double = Convert.ToDouble(45)
```

OR

```
Dim x AS Double = CDBL(45)
```